# WordPress wp_oembed_get error

Tags: php, wordpress, video, fatal-error, oembed

I'm having issues with a video shortcode in wordpress and decided to create a php script to test the wp_oembed_get function and make sure that everything was working fine, but when I call:

```
$embed_code = wp_oembed_get('http://vimeo.com/XXXX', array('width'=>400));
```

I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/xxxxx/wp-includes/cache.php on line 113
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this wp site on localhost or live?

Comment: Live... I'm trying to test the wp_oembed_get function. Is there an easy way to do this? What files are required to be able to call that function?

Comment: Try it somewhere on localhost,the problem might be with the hosting.It should work.

Comment: You also might want an account on this sister site http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30959/oembed-not-recognising-vimeo-urls

Comment: That's the problem, we sort of are the hosting as well, we need to figure out what's going on the server that's causing video embedding not to work.

Comment: With a youtube url does it work?

Comment: What are the files that I need to include in order to test this function? Same thing happened for youtube...